# ipad web app causes some divs to not display

Tags: css, ipad, web-applications

On Chrome and Safari (on the ipad) everything displays as it should. However, when I "add to home screen", only my background image shows, and the other divs dont. I think it might have something to do with the z-index or position of the other divs, but I can't figure out what to do.

CSS

```
#map{ background: url('img/map.png');} 

#map_gate{
z-index: 100;
width: 299px;
height: 313px;
top: 149px;
left: 539px;
position: absolute;
background: url('img/map_gate_closed.png');}

#map_dora{
z-index: 200;
width: 65px;
height: 91px;   
top: 473px;
left: 83px;
position: absolute;
background-image:url('img/map_dora.png');} 

.background{
z-index: 1;
top: 0;
left: 0;    
width: 1024px;
height: 768px;
position: fixed;    
display: none;
overflow: hidden;}

.selected_area {
z-index: 10;
text-align:center;
position: fixed;    
display: none;
/*background-repeat:no-repeat;*/
overflow: hidden;}
```

HTML

```
<div id="map" class="background map"></div>
<div id="map_gate" class="selected_area map"></div>
<div id="map_dora" class="selected_area map"></div>
```

Comment: I'm confused... you put display:none to .background and .selected_area, everything should disappear?

Comment: I use javascript to hide and show divs, which works. Anyway turned out that the ipad was just showing cached older versions, even though I thought deleting the web app, clearing history of safari etc would mean a fresh start... now that's another problem...

Comment: that's not i think, it's very common thing... even I clear the cache a few times, the page is still not updating... IPAD SUCKKKKKK!!! (just kidding)